# What is wrong with this NASM assembly adder?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have recently started to get into assembly, and I have been using NASM because I can easily find tutorials. Because of its difficulty, I decided I would start very small, by making a program to add 1 and 3 and output 4. I have worked it out enough that I do not receive error or warning messages, but it does not output anything aside from sh-4.3$.

```
segment .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov eax, '1'
    sub eax, '0'

    mov ecx, '3'
    sub ecx, '0'

    add ecx, eax
    add ecx, '0'

    mov edx, 1
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80
```

Comment: What OS do you do your dev work on? If it's Windows, I highly recommend using SASM as an ide and debugger. It's great if you are learning, you can step through and watch the values in each register. https://dman95.github.io/SASM/english.html

Comment: Because of various issues, I am actually forced to practice everything with NASM at, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/codingground.htm. Though from what I understand, the terminals emulate the Linux OS.

Comment: If you have a chance, I still highly recommend it. Unfortunately, the tutorialspoint coding ground doesn't have any debugger attached.

Comment: Downvoted because you don't say what it *does* do.  So it's not a [mcve].  I'd be happy to remove my downvote once you fix that.  And I'd highly encourage you to find a way to use a debugger while learning asm.  Developing asm without one is like trying to build a robot while blindfolded.  See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for more info, including gdb usage tips at the bottom.  (You can use gdb in a text terminal).

Comment: @PeterCordes I apologize, I did not intend on going against the stack exchanges conditions. Even though my question is already answered, I have edited the question. As for the debugger, I use my college's public computers which have strict rules against most installations. Is there any online NASM debugger?

Comment: Your college computers have NASM but not gdb?  That's super-weird.  You don't need a nasm-specific debugger (and I'm not sure there is any such thing).  Anyway, I thought you said you were using an online terminal.  I'd expect anything calling itself a dev environment with tools like nasm and gcc installed to also have gdb installed (or an equivalent like lldb).  Did you try running `gdb ./a.out`?

Comment: like Eric said above, the tutorialspoint coding ground terminals do not have any debuggers. If I try, it just says, gbd: command not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your result into a variable, then you display the variable :

```
section .data
    result : db ' ',10          ◄■■ VARIABLE
segment .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov eax, '1'
    sub eax, '0'

    mov ecx, '3'
    sub ecx, '0'

    add ecx, eax
    add ecx, '0'
    mov [result], cl          ◄■■ MOVE RESULT INTO THE VARIABLE.

    mov ecx, result           ◄■■ DISPLAY THIS VARIABLE.
    mov edx, 1
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80
```

You have to store the address of the variable in ECX, not the value itself.

Comment: Oh, now I feel dumb. The sys_write system call took a const char * input in ecx. I get it now. That being said, is their any possible way I can use the "memory address" of one of the registers?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I could use register addressing. Thank you Jose

Comment: @N.D.H.: you'd see the problem if you ran your program with `strace ./a.out`.  You'd see `write(...) = -EFAULT` for the system call, since you pass an invalid pointer.